Is it possible to use OpenGL ES extensions in OpenGL? If not, why?
I've been looking at KHR_texture_compression_astc_hdr for OpenGL. It seems it's only currently supported by OpenGL ES 3.2. My GPU is an Nvidia RTX A3000, which does support it for OpenGL ES contexts. It's not supported by a full OpenGL context on my card.
I guess I'm surprised by this because I have often read that OpenGL ES is a subset of OpenGL, and if my card supports it for my ES context, surely all the driver code/hardware is there to get it done.
Is there no way to somehow do a decompress pass with this extension from a full OpenGL context? Even if it requires some interop or similar.
